# Is there any way to travel from Cameroon to Kinshasa by land?

Tags: overland, democratic-republic-congo, cameroon, republic-congo

Last year I did a road trip from Dar es Salaam to Johannesburg wondering if I can still do this same trip from Cameroon to Kinshasa Congo.

I don't want to cross any river using any canoe or what so ever the route must total be by land. 
Any useful information will be appreciated.

Comment: You know it's going to be difficult, when Google refuses to give driving directions.

Comment: Google *does* give driving directions from Cameroon's capital Yaounde to Brazzaville, from where it's "just" (I've read some travelogues where it seemed quite the experience) a ferry ride to Kinshasa.

Comment: @MichaelHampton for certain European countries at least (Bosnia), Bing is far better than Google, giving house to house directions instead of city to city.  This may be true in Africa as well.

Comment: As of 2021, Google Maps will now happily give you directions from Yaoundé to Kinshasa.  But it involves the Brazzaville-Kinshasa ferry.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it!

It will probably take you a couple of days, but there are national "highways" that will take you down through Gabon (passing not far from Libreville - which would definitely be worth making the detour to see!) and all the way across the Republic of the Congo, passing very close to Dolisie (the third biggest city in the RC).

Unfortunately, unless you want to circumvent thousands of miles you will *have* to cross the Congo river by ferry, which, as davidvc mentioned, is quite the trip indeed!

Make sure all your papers are in order and be ready to tip some highway checkpoints if they start giving you trouble. 5,000 CFA (~$10 US) ought to do the trick. It can be an expensive drive!

Comment: There is a bridge across to Congo River at Matadi.  If one could cross the border into the Kongo Central province from either the RoC or Cabinda, you could conceivably drive to Matadi, cross the river there, and proceed to Kinshasa.  But it is unclear to me whether there are any border crossings between the DRC and these jurisdictions.